# Do genies exist in the Harry Potter world?

Tags: harry-potter

I don't recall seeing them in the books, but I might have missed something- are there genies in Rowling's Wizarding World?

Comment: See [this site](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Genie) (I can't find the relevant Pottermore article)

Comment: I think the FAQ answer http://web.archive.org/web/20111223101251/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours_view.cfm?id=10 from J. K. Rowling's old site applies: “Do you really think getting rid of Voldemort would be that easy?”

Answer (score 36):

Genies receive a brief *mention* in an article on Pottermore, but they don't appear to be the wish-granting kind.

> **The ceremony started in gentle style, with river Genies from the Ivory
> Coast dancing in formation over the surface of the lake.** It was only
> when the Fijian and Norwegian mascots were released that disaster
> struck.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pottermore - DISASTROUS OPENING CEREMONY LEADS TO QUESTIONS ABOUT QUIDDITCH WORLD CUP SECURITY](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/4/48/Disastrous_Opening_Ceremony_Leads_to_Questions_About_Quidditch_World_Cup_Security.png/revision/latest?cb=20150917014126)</sup></sub>

I've also searched every single piece of canon material, JKR's twitter, the old Potter website, old Pottermore website and current Wizarding World website for any use of the word *Genie, Jinn, Djinn, Jinni, Jinnee and Ifrit*, but there are no further mentions.

Comment: To be fair, while genies that grant wishes do appear in the relevant mythology, western media has heavily flanderized this trait; a genie that does not grant wishes is still a perfectly good genie in my book.

Comment: @Kevin - This is the sole and only mention, unfortunately.

Comment: _"any use of the word Genie, Jinn, Djinn, Jinni, Jinnee"_ — but there's Ginny :)

Answer (score 5):

A text search for "genie" in each of the seven books turns up no results, so it is presumably not part of the main storyline (unless under a different name or different spelling). I can't promise that it doesn't appear in any supplementary materials, though.

[image: Screenshot showing lack of results of the text search for "genie"]

Comment: "Djinn," "djinni,"  and "jinn" are common alternate spellings.  None of them show up in any of the HP books, though.

Comment: Harry Potter universe is way bigger than the original 7 books.

Comment: Well, if enchanted carpets exist in Harry Potter (which they do), and since this is a world of magic, I can’t see why genies can’t exist in Harry Potter.

Comment: @AlexDowns It's not about "they can't", it's about if their existence being acknowledged. Just the same way that in the real world it makes sense thinking there should be life on other planets, but... Yeah, who knows?